# Gulp plugin for grails 2.5.5

Tags: javascript, grails, gulp, gulp-uglify

I´m using angular in my grails platform, i need change the mimify plugin to gulp tasks

Currently we are using "asset-pipeline:2.5.7", but cache of js files doesn´t work because this plugin just mimify the files, no version.
We need put the js files in the file application.js.

Can we use the gulp to mimifier and version our js/css files in grails 2.5.5?

Answer (score 0):

You can call gulp tasks from Grails command-line and link tasks to project compilation and test phases.

Install node.js. Then install Gulp with gulp npm install gulp -g.

**Add the plugin to your `grails-app/conf/BuildConfig.groovy`**

```
plugins { 
compile ":gulp:latest.version" 
}
```

Please refer [**this**](https://github.com/hypermurea/grails-gulp-plugin) for other configuration

Hope this will helps you